# Uncaught ReferenceError JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Ok, so I have a template which I am using to print a couple of users to a table.

```
function PrintUsers(item) {
    $.template('userList', '<tr onClick="OnUserPressed(${Identifier})">\
    <td>${Firstname}</td>\
    <td>${Lastname}</td>\
    </tr>');

    $.tmpl('userList', item).appendTo("#UserTableContainer");
}
```

When I press a user I want his/hers unique identifier to be passed to a function called OnUserPressed which I am declaring in the template. The code below is just a test to see if it actually passes the data to the function.

```
    function OnUserPressed(Identifier) {
        alert(Identifier);
    }
```

My problems are these: When I press the first value in the table I get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL". When I press any other value in the table I get "Uncaught ReferenceError: xxx is not defined" where xxx is their unique identifier. So it actually retrieves the ID but I still get an error.

Any thoughts?

Comment: please provide your html markup where are you storing identifier, as tr attribute?

Comment: Have a look at the **generated** HTML... this should reveal what the problem is.

Comment: <tr onClick="OnUserPressed(${Identifier})">\
    <td>${Firstname}</td>\
    <td>${Lastname}</td>\
    </tr> try removing space from them.Put them in a single line.Do not hit return key to get to next <td>

Comment: techie_28: Thank you for your answer but it didn't work.

Comment: rahul: Yes, I intend to store the value in its tr attribute. Is this problematic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to pass the identifier to the `OnUserPressed` function as a string.

Try wrapping the `${Identifier}` template variable with single quotes:

```
<tr onClick="OnUserPressed('${Identifier}')">
```

---

Edit: Responding to comment about single quotes.

Inside your template string you can escape the single quotes by preceeding them with a backslash:

```
'<tr onClick="OnUserPressed(\'${Identifier}\')">'
```

Comment: I tried using the ´ ´ quotes since I'm surrounding the whole expression in ' ' and it didn't work either. I got "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL" on every value instead.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much! This helped me with both my errors. :)